# How can a List exist without <T> after it?

Tags: c#, list, types

I came across this situation where `List` has no type specified after it in `<>`:

```
List someVar = new List();
```

However when I try this in Visual Studio I get an error. What is the reason for VS not letting me declare `List` this way?

Let me show you where I saw it:

```
public override IEnumerable SomeMethod()
        {
            List someVar= new List();
            // more code
            return someVar;
        }
```

P.S After contacting the owner of the project it turned out Wordpress striped out the tags `<>` after `List` and `IEnumerable`, so it actually should be `List<SomeClass>` and `IEnumerable<SomeClass>`

```
public override IEnumerable<SomeClass> SomeMethod()
        {
            List<SomeClass> someVar= new List<SomeClass>();
            // more code
            return someVar;
        }
```

Comment: Is there a class declared in one of your references as List?

Comment: @Paddy: No, there is no such class.

Comment: What version of .NET are you using and what `using`'s do you have?

Comment: I saw it in an override method of a base class. Look: public override IEnumerable SomeMethod() { List produceObjects = new List(); // more code return produceObjects; }

Comment: @Todo: You have shown a code snippet, where was it declared exactly? Does this project contain a class with the name `List`? Right-click it and `go to definition`. I'm sure it's a custom class that doesn't belong to the framework.

Answer (score 7):

There is not an inbuilt class called `List`. There is `ArrayList`, but: click on `List` and press <kbd>f12</kbd>. This will show you where it is declared. There are two options:

- a class called `List` that is *nothing whatsoever to do with `List<T>`* has been declared in the local project; for example:

  ```
  class List { ...} // here we go; a class called List
  ```
- a `using` alias (at the top of the file) has been used to spoof `List` as a name; for example:

  ```
  using List = System.Collections.Hashtable;
  ```

  or

  ```
  using List = System.Collections.Generic.List<int>;
  ```

Comment: Pressing F12 goes nowhere because VS does not recognize it.

Comment: @Todo Check your project references, there might be a missing referenced assembly

Comment: @Todo I *meant* press F12 in the project where you saw it being used

Comment: @Mark: Actually I took this code from a Wordpress blog and it turned out that Wordpress stripped out <SomeText> part after List and this was the problem... otherwise it'd been a normal generic List :)

Answer (score 2):

You get an error because the `List` class does not exist in the .NET Framework. If you want to use a non-generic list that can hold any type of object, use [ArrayList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

I don't recognise it (I thought it was `ArrayList` before `List<T>` arrived?). Either way it would be an older class invented before generics was implemented. I'd use `List<object>`.